# Cannot calculate double over time within my method

Tags: c#, debugging, methods, logic

I am having trouble calculating the double over time (2.0m * the hourly rate) within my **"gross_pay"** method once the user enters hours that go over 60. I have done the regular gross pay (hours* rate of pay) that is less than or equal to 40 hours and the over time (1.5 * rate of pay) once the user goes over 40 hours, but not more than 60.

On paper, it makes sense to me, but I have a bit of a hard time translating it into code. I have been programming in C# for about 8 weeks, so a lot of things are not intuitive yet. I just left the **if (hours > 60)** statement blank for the sake of this post...I had code in there that wasn't doing anything anyways. I would appreciate any help that would guide me towards solving this problem. I have been trying to solve this for quite some time tonight, thank you for your time. This is what I have so far:

```
  //method that calculates the gross pay
    private decimal gross_pay(ref decimal hours, ref decimal rate)
    {
        decimal gross_pay = 0m;
        if (hours >60)
        {
           // do something
        }
        else if (hours >40 && hours <60)
        {
            //calculates the over time pay.
          decimal over_time = hours - 40;
            gross_pay = rate * 40 + (1.5m * rate) * over_time;
        }
        else if (hours <=40)
        {             
           gross_pay = hours * rate;
        }
        return gross_pay;
    }
```

Comment: I certainly would not want to work for exactly 60 hours for you ;-) Make sure the `<60` becomes a `<=60` so that there is no fall-through to 0. Ideally add an `else` assert or exception for the cases that you forgot!

Comment: Ask yourself: How much *do* you get when you work for 61 hours - is it the same as for 60 or is that last hour of overtime paid at the normal rate?

Comment: In the first `else if` statement you can safely leave out the `&& hours < 60` part - the first `if` already checked for that. Likewise, the last `else if` can be turned into a simple `else`. In other words: 'if it's more than 60, do this. Else, if it's at least more than 40, do this. Else, do this'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
private decimal gross_pay(ref decimal hours, ref decimal rate)
        {
            decimal gross_pay = 0m;
            if(hours > 60)
            {
                decimal over_time = 20;
                decimal double_over_time = hours - 60;
                gross_pay = rate * 40 + (1.5m * rate) * over_time + (2.0m * rate) * double_over_time;
            }
            else if (hours > 40 && hours <= 60)
            {
                //calculates the over time pay.
                decimal over_time = hours - 40;
                gross_pay = rate * 40 + (1.5m * rate) * over_time;
            }
            else if (hours <= 40)
            {
                gross_pay = hours * rate;
            }
            return gross_pay;
        }
```

Make sure you distinguish between `over_time` (paid 1.5 * rate) and `double_over_time` (paid 2.0 * rate). In the scenario where someone worked for over 60 hours, `over_time` will be always 20 hours :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I greatly appreciate it. I think you might have mixed up your over_time and double_over_time values. I switched them around after I received $800.00 as an output for 65 hours of work at $10.00/hour, which turns into 40 hours at $10.00, 5 at $15.00, and the last twenty at 20.00 to equal $875.00  :)

 I used this website as a reference: <http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/gross-pay-calculator.php>

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```
private decimal gross_pay(decimal hours, decimal rate)
    {
        var standardRateHours = Math.Min(40, hours);
        var overTimeRateHours = Math.Min(Math.Min(hours, 60) - standardRateHours, 20);
        var doubleRateHours = Math.Max(hours - 60, 0);

        var grossPay = standardRateHours*rate + overTimeRateHours*1.5m*rate + doubleRateHours*2*rate;

        return grossPay;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like the most readable solution to me. Simple and to the point.